# Access the values in array php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to access the values of an array.

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [action_type] => comment [value] => 19074.125 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [action_type] => like [value] => 2179.9 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [action_type] => link_click [value] => 16.633202528886 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [action_type] => offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_add_to_cart [value] => 451.45857988166 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [action_type] => offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_complete_registration [value] => 897.60588235294 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [action_type] => offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_initiate_checkout [value] => 1230.5887096774 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [action_type] => offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_lead [value] => 372.17804878049 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [action_type] => offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase [value] => 2384.265625 ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [action_type] => offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_view_content [value] => 63.316597510373 ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [action_type] => post [value] => 8477.3888888889 ) [10] => stdClass Object ( [action_type] => post_like [value] => 193.15569620253 ) [11] => stdClass Object ( [action_type] => unlike [value] => 76296.5 ) [12] => stdClass Object ( [action_type] => page_engagement [value] => 15.168290258449 ) [13] => stdClass Object ( [action_type] => post_engagement [value] => 15.274574574575 ) [14] => stdClass Object ( [action_type] => offsite_conversion [value] => 43.39960182025 ) )
```

I need to access the value of [action_type] => offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase [value] => 2384.265625 , how to get the value of only offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase ??

these values comes from the foreach loop.

```
     $r  = $i->cost_per_action_type;

    foreach($r as $key => $value){
       echo $key["action_type"];
}
```

the array you are seeing is the print_r($x).

Comment: Why are you JSON-encoding and then decoding...?!

Comment: Might be `echo $key[0]->action_type;`

Comment: @deceze if i echo out $r , i will get Array to string conversion error!

Comment: ^^^ that's why you iterate to it right? Why don't just `foreach($r as $key => $value)` ?

Comment: so, how would we access the action_type of offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase and getting its value?

Comment: action_type (key) offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase(value) and [value] => 1234. need the value of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to treat object as array which doesn't simply working. Use arrow operator `->` instead to get object value.

```
foreach($r as $val){
    echo $val->action_type;
}
```

In case you're really wanted it to be an array, make sure to implement interfaces that gives ability to treat object as an array [`ArrayAccess`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php), [`Countable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php), etc. You can also extends [`ArrayObject`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) class, too.

And, according to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202844/access-the-values-in-array-php#comment63830562_38202844)

```
foreach($r as $val){
    if ($val->action_type == 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase') {
        echo $val->value;
    }
}
```

Comment: but i am using the raw php , just access the object to retrieve the values from api, and not using classes . also i m getting this error  Trying to get property of non-object, so any solution around this?

Comment: Look here https://3v4l.org/6M2I3 There must be an error coming from your API response. Try to wrap it with `isset`.

Comment: need to wrap if(isset($val->action_type)){}?

Comment: I wasn't look your comment properly `Trying to get property of non-object` means `$val` isn't an object. Look at the another answer above mine.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the result as an array and not as object, use:

```
//will return an associative array
$x = json_decode($j, true);
```

In your code $x is an object, not array, so that foreach is incorrect. You should work on your code and give some reasons for witch you encoded an array just to decode it and try to use it like an array not as object.

You should change the Object to array if you are using the array and got rid of the encode.
You can do what @Chay22 did in the example as array:

```
foreach($r as $val){
    if ($val[action_type] == 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase') {
        echo $val[value];
    }
}
```